# Runtime Error 424 appears when IDE not installed

Tags: vb6

hello i wrote a VB6 app and when i run the app on a computer that doesn't have VB6 IDE
i get an error: ERROR: Runtime Error 424 Object Required

but when i install VB6 IDE the app works ok!

are there any dll's i'm missing?

thank you

Comment: Are you installing the VB runtime files, or installing on a computer that already has the runtime installed? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417

Answer (score 0):

When you run a Visual Basic for Applications macro that uses Data Access Object it will generate the following error :

```
Run-time Error '424':
```

or the more possibility is there while the dao object is not properly written/registered or ur dao dll's might corrupted

to solve this :

> On the Start menu, click Run. In the Open box, type regedit, and then
>   click OK.
>
> Open the following registry key:
>
> ```
>       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Current
>       Version/SharedDLLs
> ```
>
> Click the following value in the SharedDLLs folder:
>
> ```
>       C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao3032.dll
> ```
>
> If you are using Microsoft Excel 97, click the following value in the SharedDLLs folder:
>
> ```
>       C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL
> ```
>
> On the Edit menu, click Modify. The edit DWORD value dialog box appears. If the value data box value is greater than 1, change it to1, and then click OK.
>       On the Registry menu, click Exit.
>       Run the Microsoft Office Setup program in maintenance mode. When you are prompted, click Remove All.
>       When you are prompted to remove shared components, click Remove All.
>
> ```
> If you are prompted to restart the computer after Setup is completed, do so.
> Install Microsoft Office.
> ```

For additional reference refer [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163475).